# Numpy: import error for python2.7 after get-apt upgrade

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-16.04, conda

Today, I have decided to upgrade my software packages:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that, I am trying to launch my python2 code and the error appears:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have tried `pip install numpy`, but got a message

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.15.1)
```

`pip2 install numpy` produces an exception:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 18.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==8.1.1'))
```

`conda install numpy` results in

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

`which python` gives me

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
```

`which pip` results in

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

What could be the problem? Seems like `numpy` cannot be installed for python2 because it is already installed for python3. I suppose, something went wrong with python2 vs python3 linkage in conda? Is it a problem with python, numpy, pip, conda or environments?

Comment: did you tryied easy_install?

Comment: @SkillerDz Yes, after `easy_install numpy` the problem persists.

Comment: Notice the messages that say python3.5? Are your paths mixed up with Python 2.x and Python 3.x?

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, looks like that

Comment: I decided to create a new virtualenv and to install all the dependencies there

Comment: Can you try and use the pip2 to install numpy?
You can try something like `which -a pip` to get all the available versions